# Invalid character

Tags: c#, sql, clr

I am creating CLR assembly for sql server which save some data from database into excel file. 
It works ok until I get invalid character error from database:

> System.ArgumentException: '', hexadecimal value 0x04, is an invalid character.

The problem is that file remains locked and I can't delete it until next execution of this CLR procedure. How can I unlock the file when error happens or even delete it?

Another question? Can I save excel file with invalid character?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using ClosedXML.Excel;

[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, Name = "FullTrust")]
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void createExcel(SqlString procName, SqlString fileName, SqlString filePath, SqlXml xmlParams, out SqlBoolean result)
    {
        result = false;
        DataSet exportData = new DataSet();

        if (procName.Value == string.Empty)
            throw new Exception("Procedure name value is missing.");

        if (filePath.Value == string.Empty)
            throw new Exception("Missing file path location.");

        if (fileName.Value == string.Empty)
            throw new Exception("Missing name of file.");

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand getOutput = new SqlCommand())
            {

                getOutput.CommandText = procName.ToString(); ;
                getOutput.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                getOutput.CommandTimeout = 300;
                getOutput.Connection = conn;

                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(getOutput))
                {
                    da.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;//drugače da pokliče na koncu AcceptChanges in hasChanges je vedno false
                    da.Fill(exportData);
                    conn.Close();
                    da.Dispose();

                    try
                    {
                        if (exportData.HasChanges())
                        {
                            using (XLWorkbook xlWb = new XLWorkbook(XLEventTracking.Disabled))
                            {
                                xlWb.Worksheets.Add(exportData.Tables[0]);
                                xlWb.SaveAs(filePath.ToString() + fileName.ToString());
                                result = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        exportData.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: I'm guessing this is more related to the `XLWorkbook` than the code you have posted, do you have the code for that or is it a 3rd party component?

Comment: `exportData.Dispose()` like that smells funny. (It could be who's holding on to the file handle too) You should probably either `using` it or use a try-finally block to make sure it's disposed in every case.

Comment: Are you defining any constants variable?

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, U+0004 is [EOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character).

Comment: This is message from Call Stack window:
SqlCreateExcel!StoredProcedures.createExcel(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString procName, System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString fileName, System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString filePath, System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml xmlParams, out System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean result) Line 58 C#

XLWorkbook is from closedxml.dll NET3.5 version, which is 3rd party dll with open source code:
[link]http://closedxml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/78389

I have moved  exportData.Dispose() to finally method , but error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution here it would be to sanitize the data. Try to do that either inside the stored procedure which returns the data, I believe it's the best way.

If that's not possible, you might want to do that inside the CLR assembly: use a `SqlDataReader` instead of the `SqlDataAdapter`, sanitize each retrieved value and add these values cell by cell.

Comment: That is one solution but it requires a lot of work for SQL server.
Why not just write invalid character as some square or mark instead of error?
If I copy data directly from database to execel file I get square on the place of invalid character and not error.